# Creating a button function with parameter

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a simple note app. Each note has a title, a body and a complete status. I want to create it so that if a note is not completed, it creates a button under the note. Upon clicking the button it should change the boolean value of complete to true and repopulate the list.

The problem I'm experiencing is that if the title has a space in it, I get an error:

[image: Picture of error in console]

This only happens when there is a space in the title(clicked on Family time). Does anyone know what the issue is? I've tried to create `note.title` as a variable then add it in. I've also tried to `note.title.toString()` with no luck. Here is the function:

```
function populateList(theList)
{
    let divList = document.querySelector('#ListDiv');
    divList.innerHTML = "";
    theList.forEach(function(note)
    {
        let element = document.createElement('p');
        let titleName = note.title.toLowerCase();
        element.innerHTML = `Title: ${note.title}<br>Body: ${note.body}<br>Completed:${note.completed}`;
        if(note.completed == false)
        {
            element.innerHTML += `<br><button onclick=completeNote("${note.title}")>Complete</button>`;
        }
        divList.appendChild(element);
    });
}
```

Comment: Where did you get this syntax from? Looks weird to me.

Comment: What is line 21 of your index.html page?

Comment: `element.innerHTML += \`<br><button onclick='completeNote("${note.title}")'>Complete</button>\`;`

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Ive followed a udemy class. Learned to use `` so i can add javascript variables straight in by using ${} instead of concatinating with +

@Mr.Polywhirl i tried to check that, but it wont show anything. Probably because the line is added through javascript.

@MiroslavGlamuzina i tried that, sadly still the same issue. il try the answer from Mr Polywhirl below

Comment: You can open the debugger and jump to the line of code (aka #21) that was throwing the error. You can also toggle stop on exceptions in the Chrome debugger and it will jump to the line in your script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a note ID to your objects and when you click the button, pass the ID to the function to find the node and set it's status to completed.

After you change the status, re-render the list.

```js
const notes = [
  { id: 1, title: 'Morning', body: 'Get out of bed', completed: true },
  { id: 2, title: 'Day', body: 'Work', completed: false },
  { id: 3, title: 'Evening', body: 'Go to bed', completed: false }
];

populateList(notes);

function completeNote(noteId) {
  notes.find(note => note.id === parseInt(noteId, 10)).completed = true;
  populateList(notes);
}

function populateList(theList) {
  const divList = document.querySelector('#ListDiv');
  divList.innerHTML = "";
  theList.forEach(note => {
    let element = document.createElement('p');
    let titleName = note.title.toLowerCase();
    element.innerHTML = `Title: ${note.title}<br>Body: ${note.body}<br>Completed: ${note.completed}`;
    if (note.completed == false) {
      element.innerHTML += `<br><button onclick=completeNote("${note.id}")>Complete</button>`;
    }
    divList.appendChild(element);
  });
}
```

```html
<div id="ListDiv"></div>
```

Comment: Using an id worked like a charm. Thanks!
I would still love to know why it didnt work with a space in the title... Just odd that it works when there is no spacing. Hope someone can shed som light on what the problem was to begin with. Thanks again.

Comment: @LowlyCoder well, your code looks fine the way it was, you were wrapping the title in quotes so I didn't see a problem. But since you didn't show your `completeNote` function, I didn't know what it was doing with the title. As long as your titles are _unique_, you should be able to find a note by it's `title` just as you can with the `id` as seen above. Try passing the title again and finding the note by title instead of id.

Answer (score 2):

Here you can use encodeURIComponent & decodeURIComponent like below:

```
function populateList(theList)
{
    let divList = document.querySelector('#ListDiv');
    divList.innerHTML = "";

    theList.forEach(function(note)
    {
        let element = document.createElement('p');
        let titleName = note.title.toLowerCase();
        element.innerHTML = `Title: ${note.title}<br>Body: ${note.body}<br>Completed:${note.completed}`;
        if(note.completed == false)
        {
            element.innerHTML += "<br><button onclick=completeNote('" + encodeURIComponent(note.title) + "')>Complete</button>";
        }
        divList.appendChild(element);
    });
}

function completeNote(title){
    theList.forEach(x=>{if(x.title == decodeURIComponent(title)){x.completed =true}});
    populateList(theList);
}
```